# How can I log/trap exceptions thrown by the ASP.NET SqlMembershipProvider?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, log4net, sqlmembershipprovider

I have a .NET 4 WebAPI app that's using the ASP.NET SqlMembershipProvider.

When it works, it works fine - but if there's any problems connecting to the membership database, I just get a silent failure and the browser shows an HTTP 500 server error.

I'm using log4net to log application warnings and errors, but I cannot work out how - or where - to catch exceptions raised by the SqlMembershipProvider so they can be logged. Using Application_Error or explicitly attaching a handler to the application's Error event doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the Event logger? Also, is log4net configured correctly? I've had a lot of problems with it in the past, which has generally made me use NLog as at least with that I can get it to complain lots when things go wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating custom error filter and registering it in global.asax?

Your 500 seems like internal server error that wasn't handled.

To avoid copy-pasting my code or code from tutorial, visit this link and it should give you enough answer. You can trigger your logging within action filter:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/exception-handling